# Why does Samuel turn to leave and then kill agag?

Tags: death, malchut-royalty, samuel-shmuel-book-of, amalek, shmuel--the-man

In Samuel I 15:27 Samuel turns to leave then Saul admits guilt, asks for forgiveness, and prostrates, and then Samuel summons Agag and kills him.

It seems that had Saul not stopped Samuel, he would have left.
Why would Samuel not, in any case, have Agag brought to him before leaving?

Comment: As I read it, Samuel and Saul were not in the same place as the rest of the people, when they had their conversation. Samuel intended to leave Saul, and go alone to the people, to deal with Agag. At Saul's request, he goes with Saul, and after Saul bows before God, he proceeds to deal with Agag.